# Redirecting non-www to www with RewriteRules.config

Tags: windows-server-2008, umbraco

would like to redirect example.com to www.example.com and  example.de to www.example.de

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRuleCOM" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule> 
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRuleDE" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^example\.de$" />
      </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.de/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following for .COM & .DE

**.com**

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW COM" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url=".*" /> 
  <conditions> 
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" /> 
  </conditions> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

**.de**

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW DE" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url=".*" /> 
  <conditions> 
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.de$" /> 
  </conditions> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.de/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

I hope this would help